# how to pass objects through a button eventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, buttonclick, dynamic-controls

I have a winform that has several modules that are created dynamically based on information in a database. each of these modules has an edit button. I want to be able to pass in an object through to the click handler and then to the new form yet I cannot figure out how. Any help would be awsome here is what i have:

```
PingServer temp = manager.servers.ElementAt(i).Value;

EditButton.Click += new EventHandler(openEditor(temp));

private void openEditor(PingServer server)       
{            
    EditConnectionForm editConnection = new EditConnectionForm(server);
    editConnection.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close over the variable using a lambda:

```
EditButton.Click += (sender, args) => openEditor(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked exactly the way I needed it. do you have any tutorials or documentation about lambda as im not too familiar with the technique

Comment: @user2952817 Not really, but Google knows of a few thousand, I'm sure you can find one that you like, which is why I gave you the proper term, so you'll have something to search on.

Comment: @user2952817 looks like Bing or Google had been off. Even if that happened, we still have Yahoo!Search (my favourite search engine in the old days :) and many others. `Lambda express` is very easy to make familiar with.